# Controling MediaElement and its source in MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mediaelement

I have DataGrid with list of video clips and MediaElement which should play a clip selected in that DataGrid. I've managed to achieve this by doing this:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid_Video"
...
SelectedItem="{Binding fosaModel.SelectedVideo}"
                  SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                  SelectionMode="Single">
...
<MediaElement x:Name="PlayerWindow" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="236" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="431" Margin="202,0,0,0" Source="{Binding fosaModel.SelectedVideo.fPath}"/>
```

But then I have no control over playback. So I searched a little bit, and I found this solution, and implemented Play button:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
...
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Player}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="236" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="431" Margin="202,0,0,0"/>
...
<Button x:Name="playButton" Content="Odtwórz" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="202,273,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" IsDefault="True" Command="{Binding PlayVideoCommand}"/>
...
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
          ...
            Player = new MediaElement()
            {
                LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual,
            };
            PlayVideoCommand = new RelayCommand(() => { _playVideoCommand(); });
    ...
        public MediaElement Player{ get; set; }
        private void _playVideoCommand()
        {
            Player.Source = new System.Uri(fosaModel.SelectedVideo.fPath);
            Player.Play();
        }
```

**fosaModel.cs**

```
public class fosaModel : INotifyPropertyChanged

{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<fosaVideo> ListOfVideos { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<fosaVideo>();
    public ObservableCollection<fosaAudio> ListOfAudios { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<fosaAudio>();
    public fosaVideo SelectedVideo { get; set; }
}
```

So now selected video is played when I press play button. Changing selection doesn't change the source of MediaElement, like it did earlier. What I want is to have control over playback of video, but also to have selecting other video in DataGrid change the source of MediaElement. Is there anyway to do so without breaking the MVVM pattern? 
I'm new to WPF, and I'm feeling like I'm missing something basic. I use MVVM Light and Fody.PropertyChanged.

### **EDIT:**

I went with Peter Moore's answer and Play/Stop feature works like a charm. But now I would like to have control over position of playback of a video. I've made another attached property:

```
public class MediaElementAttached : DependencyObject
{
   ...
   #region VideoProgress Property

    public static DependencyProperty VideoProgressProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "VideoProgress", typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(MediaElementAttached),
            new PropertyMetadata(new TimeSpan(0,0,0), OnVideoProgressChanged));
    public static TimeSpan GetVideoProgress(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (TimeSpan)d.GetValue(VideoProgressProperty);
    }
    public static void SetVideoProgress(DependencyObject d, TimeSpan value)
    {
        d.SetValue(VideoProgressProperty, value);
    }
    private static void OnVideoProgressChanged(
        DependencyObject obj,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        MediaElement me = obj as MediaElement;
        me.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        if (me == null)
            return;
        TimeSpan videoProgress = (TimeSpan)args.NewValue;
        me.Position = videoProgress;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<MediaElement 
    ... 
    local:MediaElementAttached.VideoProgress="{Binding fosaModel.videoProgress, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="playerWindow" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="236" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="431" Margin="202,0,0,0" Source="{Binding fosaModel.SelectedVideo.fPath}" LoadedBehavior="Manual" />
```

I can set value of it, when I change `videoProgress` property, but I can't get the position of video playback, that is, `videoProgress` isn't updating as video is played. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried to add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to your Binding in MediaElement?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work. Notice that I'm using ContentControl now to implement playback controls in my ViewModel.

Comment: have checked (in debugger?) if the Selected Item really has changed on selection?

Comment: I don't think I have to do that, since pressing Play after selecting another video make MediaElement to play that video. So SelectedVideo update's properly, but I don't know how to update source of MediaElement in the same way as SelectedVideo updates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you're going to have to employ a hack no matter what, because `MediaElement` is not MVVM friendly by default.

Attached properties can be very useful in situations like this though and you can do what you want to do without really breaking the pattern (or at least, not in a way that would upset anyone). You could create an attached `DependencyProperty` for `MediaElement` called `IsPlaying`. In the property change handler, you could either Play or Stop the MediaElement depending on the new value of the property. Something like this might work:

```
    public class MediaElementAttached : DependencyObject
    {
        #region IsPlaying Property

        public static DependencyProperty IsPlayingProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "IsPlaying", typeof(bool), typeof(MediaElementAttached ),
                new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsPlayingChanged));
        public static bool GetIsPlaying(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (bool)d.GetValue(IsPlayingProperty);
        }
        public static void SetIsPlaying(DependencyObject d, bool value)
        {
            d.SetValue(IsPlayingProperty, value);
        }
        private static void OnIsPlayingChanged(
            DependencyObject obj,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            MediaElement me = obj as MediaElement;
            if (me == null)
                return;
            bool isPlaying = (bool)args.NewValue;
            if (isPlaying)
                me.Play();
            else
                me.Stop();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Then make an `IsPlaying` property in your view model, and bind it to the attached property `MediaElementAttached.IsPlaying` on the `MediaElement`.

Just keep in mind the binding will only be one-way: you'll be able to control the MediaElement, but you won't be able to use your view model to learn the value of `IsPlaying` if the user changes the playback state with the transport controls. But you can't really do that with `MediaElement` anyway, so you're not giving up anything.

As with most things there are multiple ways to skin this cat, but this is my personal preference and keeps you closest to the pattern I think. This way you can at least get that ugly reference to `MediaElement` out of your view model code.

Also as far as the video not changing with the selection, the way you have it now, the `MediaElement`'s `Source` property isn't bound to anything because you're creating it in code, so it's not going to change just because `SelectedVideo` changes. I would go back to the way you had it before, and try my attached property solution.

**Edit** -
As far as the `Position` issue goes, it's the same as what I mentioned with `IsPlaying`, i.e., you can only use these attached properties as one-way setters; you can't use them to obtain the value of anything on the `MediaElement`. But you have another problem too when it comes to `Position` which is that it isn't a `DependencyProperty`, so there's no way to get a notification as to when it actually changes and thus no way to update your attached property with a new value (probably because the updates are so fast and frequent they would bog down the system quite a bit). The only solution I can think of is to poll the `MediaElement` at some interval (something like 100ms shouldn't be too bad) and then set your attached property with every poll. I would do that in your View's code-behind. Make sure to employ a thread lock and some kind of "suspend update" flag too so you can make sure the `MediaElement`'s `Position` is not updated during a poll event. Hope this helps.

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged` should  be raised as OP uses Fody.PropertyChanged

Comment: Oh, I'm unfamiliar with that library. Interesting, thanks.

Comment: I think there should be `MediaElementAttached` instead of `AttachedProperty`, and `true` (or `false`) instead of `null` in `new PropertyMetadata(null, OnIsPlayingChanged));`

Comment: I don't understand how exactly control the playback now. What should I put in my `_PlayVideoCommand` to play a video?

Comment: this.IsPlaying = true; But you also have to bind that attached property to a new IsPlaying property for your view model.

Comment: Really thanks, works perfectly. Last question - can I add another attached property in this `MediaElementAttached` class to have control over progress of video using your solution as a some kind of template (I'm guessing that that would be of int type)? What would be different?

Oh, and there should be `me.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;` after `MediaElement me = obj as MediaElement;`, because you can't control the playback of MediaElement by default.

Comment: You're welcome, and you sure can. Probably make it a TimeSpan type to match MediaElement.Position  (which I have no idea why is not a DependencyProperty)

Comment: I've edited my question regarding MediaElement.Position, I would really appreciate it, if you would look up into it.

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.